# Variable set with ng-init is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am a beginner in AngularJS (and JS for that matter), and I'm having the following problem.

Here is the html template:

```
<ion-view view-title="Playlists">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="playlist in playlists" ng-init="pageID=playlist.id" href="#/app/music/{{playlist.id}}">
            {{playlist.title}} {{pageID}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And here is the controller:

```
.controller('MusicCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.playlists = [
    { title: 'Reggae', id: 1 },
    { title: 'Chill', id: 2 },
    { title: 'Dubstep', id: 3 },
    { title: 'Indie', id: 4 },
    { title: 'Rap', id: 5 },
    { title: 'Cowbell', id: 6 }
  ];
  $scope.$watch('pageID', function () {
    console.log($scope.pageID); 
  });
```

{{pageID}} displays correctly on the page, however in the console, pageID is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: I am only trying to access the playlist.id in the controller, and my idea was to set a $scope variable equal to playlist.id

Comment: @Guillaume  So why don't you achieve it in controller instead ng-init ?

Comment: @Vineet when I click on one of the playlist, I go to this view: http://pastebin.com/LeCje12C
What I'm trying to achieve hre is to have my view-title be the title of the corresponding playlist... I am extremely new to all of this, and am probably formulating my questions awkwardly

Comment: @Guillaume I don't know why you're using `wathcers`. Watchers watches the variable value and see the value is changes or not. In your case you should try `$scope.$watch('pageID', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(newValue); 
  });`

Comment: actually I was looking at my issue the wrong way, I don't need ng-init or watchers, I just need to use $index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pageid is `undefined` in the console its because you have not defined it in your controller but just assigning value in ng-init. So you may use this inside your controller and then you won't get `undefined`.

```
.controller('MusicCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.pageID = 1;//just an example
```